# How do I give my app directory the correct permissions in order to run docker-compose up?

Tags: meteor, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am very new to **Docker Images**. I have therefore been following a tutorial about how to run [Docker Image for Meteor Apps](https://hub.docker.com/r/geoffreybooth/meteor-base/). It seems like I managed to install the `Base Docker Image for Meteor Apps` from https://hub.docker.com/r/geoffreybooth/meteor-base/ which I now am having issues running on my remote server while using the `docker-compose up` command.

The below is what I get after running `docker-compose up`:
[image: A screenshot of the "building app" process]

I thought using `sudo docker-compose up` might help but I still get the following:

[image: A screenshot when using sudo docker-compose command]

Can someone kindly help point out how to resolve this issue.

Find below my environment details, hopefully you will find them of use in the attempt to help me:

I thought there might be something wrong with my docker installation so I run: `sudo docker run hello-world` but the message:  `Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly....` suggests that the installation is fine.

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE  DRIVER  STATE  URL  SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
```

Find below the contents of my folder. Note that the app is the folder containing my app.

```
$ ls
Dockerfile  app  docker-compose.yml
```

The content of `Dockerfile` is copied and pasted from [Dockerfile content](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/disney/meteor-base/master/example/Dockerfile):

The content of `docker-compose.yml` is copied and pasted from [docker-compose.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/disney/meteor-base/master/example/docker-compose.yml)

also the contents of .dockerignore is copied and pasted from [.dockerignore](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/disney/meteor-base/master/example/.dockerignore).

Kindly let me know if there is any other environment that I need to expose.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: This is not an answer, merely a suggestionI usually run ```meteor build``` to generate nodejs app then copy it to a tiny nodejs image and it works